# how to clone one job with jenkins API

Tags: api, jenkins

How to clone one job with Jenkins API? Is there any Jenkins API supporting this?

I have one job

```
http://{jenkins-endpoint}/jenkins/job/test1/job1
```

I want to clone the job1 to one new job:

```
http://{jenkins-endpoint}/jenkins/job/test2/job2.
```

Comment: Please Change the URL It will redirect to the xxx.com which is a porn site.

Comment: Just an advice please check twice before posting anything.

Comment: it can use the jenkins-cli  java -jar jenkins-cli.jar copy-job SRC DST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can use Jenkins CLI copy command.

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar copy-job SRC DST
```